# Can you express 'thousands' in number?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Is there any plausible way of expressing a sentence like

> There are **thousands** of people in this city

Could you express that with numbers? Using the figure 1000 would make it look like *"a thousand people in this city"*

Comment: Why do you want to do that? 1000s.

Comment: @sumelic If I said _There are 1000s of people here_ , would it be understandable to most people? I want to replace the word with the number.

Comment: As sumelic says, you can write, "There are 1000s of people in this city"  However it seems a pointless thing to do. Why do you wish to do it?

Comment: @chazlyfromUK Then its problem solved. Someone needs to make an answer

Comment: Interesting question. I think the very purpose of a word like _thousands_ is to escape putting in a definite number. It's a range, and a conveniently wide one at that.

Comment: there you go. If you are using it in writing I suggest using thousands but if you are using it in writing in a business standpoint or citing facts, use the number form

Comment: I'd suggest using "thousands" even when writing about business or citing facts. The only use I can see for "1000s" is that it saves a few characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to your question ,the definition of thousands based off of [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thousands?s=t)

> **Thousands**  
> the numbers between 1000 and 999,999, as in referring to an amount of something: *Property damage was in the thousands.*

The plural number form to express thousands:

```
1000s American and common universal according to spellcheckers 
1000's British (old school)
Although using an apostrophe-S to make a number plural is somewhat common, it is incorrect.
```

Just one quick bit of advice: If you state "1000s", make sure you have at least 2 thousand, the minimum required for plural of one thousand to make it grammatically correct.

Thus: 1000s is the grammatically correct answer.

Comment: Personally, I would not use "thousands" to mean "hundreds of thousands."

Comment: Where is your second quotation from? // Your final comment is not strictly accepted by everyone.

Comment: which last comment?

Comment: There are at least two statements you made that I don't think everyone would accept:  "Although using an apostrophe-S to make a number plural is somewhat common, it is incorrect" and " If you state "1000s", make sure you have at least 2 thousand, the minimum required for plural of one thousand to make it grammatically correct". See the discussions at the following questions: [Plurals of acronyms, letters, numbers — use an apostrophe or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not/55978#55978)...

Comment: ...and [When does thousand turn into thousands?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140991/when-does-thousand-turn-into-thousands).

Comment: well it has to be more than 1 thousand so 2 thousand + can be considered  Thousands or 1000s

Comment: I would say that every sentence here is disputable, not to say tendentious. Since '1000' is not a word, it has no 'correct' plural. Since it is pronounced 'one thousand', "1000's" is clearly 'one thousands', which is not a 'grammatically correct' form however often advertisements use it.  Your second quotation is incoherent: common usage in America makes one form correct, but common usage elsewhere makes another form incorrect?!. And you can't drag dictionary.com into your corner when it never mentions *1000's*.